# Consequences of Jailbreaking as a Developer

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, jailbreak, apple-developer

What would be the consequences of Jailbreaking my iOS device as a developer?

What are some of the benefits, and what are some of the issues with Jailbreaking as a developer?

How would this effect Xcode when "paired" with my iPod?

(Should I ask this on Stackoverflow?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jailbreaking has become legal some time ago. So from that point of view, no worries.

If you have an untethered jailbreak on your iPod (and even if you have a tethered one), pairing should not prove a problem.

The true upside is that, in the case your app does not meet the Apple requirements, you could always release it as a jailbreak app in the cydia store.